# URLconf not working with similar URLs

Tags: python, django

Here is my URLconf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^new_player/$', new_player, name="new_player"),
    url(r'^new_player/player_added/$', player_added, name="player_added"),
    url(r'^(\d+)/new_avatar/$', new_avatar, name='new_avatar' ),
    url(r'^(?P<user_name>[-\w]+)/new_game/$', new_game, name='new_game' ),
    url(r'^$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list', { 'queryset': Player.objects.all(),'extra_context': {'players' : Player.objects.annotate(total_amount_won=Sum('avatar__games__profit'))}}, 'stakeme_player_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<real_name>[\w|\W]+)/', usernames_by_player),
    url(r'^(?P<user_name>[\w|\W]+)/', avatars_by_username),
)
```

As written above, `url(r'^(?P<real_name>[\w|\W]+)/', usernames_by_player),` will display it's associated template, but `url(r'^(?P<user_name>[\w|\W]+)/', avatars_by_username),` will 404.

If I reverse the order of the last two URLs, the 404 will display for `usernames_by_player` instead of `avatars_by_username`

I can see how, due to the similar URL patterns, this could cause a problem but could someone explain why and how to resolve please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those urls are looked up in the order you defined them. So this line `url(r'^(?P<real_name>[\w|\W]+)/', usernames_by_player)` grabs all input from the request url. You should distinguish these urls like:

```
url(r'^realname/(?P<real_name>[\w|\W]+)/', usernames_by_player),
url(r'^username/(?P<user_name>[\w|\W]+)/', avatars_by_username),
```

Hope this leads into the right direction.

Comment: This does help, and was actually the direction I was going to head. Is there a way to keep the original format though?

Comment: Ideally, I would like my urls to be as I have them in the OP. For instance, if my username were Dan123 and my real name were Daniel, I would want /project/Daniel/ to point me to my `usernames_by_player` and /project/Dan123/ to point me to `avatars_by_username`. I understand this would assume that no Real Name is ever the same as User Name - so assuming that was true, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Regardless, I'm going to accept your answer since I don't think I can assume that User Name will never be the same as Real Name

Comment: theoretically, yes, there is a way, just pass the name via url to your view and try to get a username and if this fails look for a realname.

Comment: Ok. The more I think about it, the more it seems like bad practice. Thank you for your answer!